# DOM not changing when I edit react's app.css in source tab of dev tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner in react js. when I'm learning about developer tools in chrome, I tried to make some changes in CSS in the elements panel, and by that, I can see the changes above in the DOM. In the sources tab, I can modify the files, but I can't make any changes to the dom. and js files also show an error that import can't work out of the source folder.

can anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have seen this is special restriction added by developers of create-react-app.

It is implemented in ModuleScopePlugin to ensure files reside in src/. That plugin ensures that relative imports from app's source directory don't reach outside of it.You can disable this feature (one of the ways) by eject operation of create-react-app project.

Most features and its updates are hidden into the internals of create-react-app system. If you make eject you will no more have some features and its update.

So if you are not ready to manage and configure application included to configure webpack and so on - do not do eject operation.Play by the existing rules (move to src).

But now you can know how to remove restriction: do eject and remove ModuleScopePlugin from webpack configuration file.It worked for me hope that works for you too.